# AngularJS - How to append json to another json object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, append

So I've to different objects, getting data from different sources. I need to convert them into a single object so that I can ng-repeat them.

```
object1 = {
"key1":"value one",
"key2":"value two"
}

object2 = {
"key1":"value three",
"key2":"value four"
}
```

What I need is

```
object3 = [{
"key1":"value one",
"key2":"value two"},
{
"key1":"value one",
"key2":"value two"}
}];
```

I tried angular.merge but it only works if the keys are different. In my case, keys are gonna be the same, only data is gonna change.

Can anyone help append `object1` to `object2` to create something like `object3` which is `object1+object2`.

I tried converting them to json string & concatenating them but it didn't work.
Array contact function is not working either.

Comment: Read [ask]. Then create MCVE. This is **very** simple, but you need to fix your question. Besides, you need to learn JavaScript.

Comment: what you want to make is an array of objects. look up Arrays.

Comment: Please do some basic research before asking questions on StackOverflow. See [JS Tutorial - JavaScript Array Methods](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp).

Comment: Guys, I understand you care about community guidelines and keeping stackoverflow's content of good quality, but I've been fighting with this question over a week, doing research as much as possible. Since I didn't get answer, that's why I asked question.

Answer (score 3):

This is just vanilla javascript. You want to make an array of from the objects.

```js
var object1 = {
  "key1": "value one",
  "key2": "value two"
}

var object2 = {
  "key1": "value three",
  "key2": "value four"
}

var object3 = []; // empty array

// add the other objects to the array
object3.push(object1);
object3.push(object2);
```

if your objects are already arrays and you just want to concatenate them, you can use the **concat** function on arrays.

```js
var object1 = [{
  key: 'abc',
  value: 1
}];
var object2 = [{
  key: 'cbd',
  value: 2
}];

// use the concat function to concatenate the arrays
var object3 = object1.concat(object2);
```

You can find more about arrays by reading the documentation found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

If your objects are firebaseArray objects they have their own API. More can be found [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata).

Comment: Alright, your solution works when object1 & 2 are like {"key":"value"}. But in my case, I'm getting object1 as [{"key":"value"}]. So resulting object3 is getting something like this: [[{"key":"value1"}],["key":"value 2"]]

Comment: @Vineonardo so object1 and object2 are already arrays? and you just want to concatenate them?

Comment: that's what I'm trying but it's not working. It says concat is not a function.

Comment: @Vineonardo I added an example on how to concatenate arrays. You should take some time and read the documentation for them too. The link is in the answer.

Comment: I'll read that, thanks. I'm a js noob so understanding core concepts is taking time. Idk why it says concat won't work since concat not a function.

Comment: If it matters, the data I'm getting is a firebaseArray which I'm getting using angularfire.

Comment: it will only work only if the both object1 and object2 are arrays, otherwise you'll need to do something else. Please edit your question to include **exactly** how object1 and object2 are.